# why host-gw of flannel requires direct layer2 connectivity between hosts?

Tags: kubernetes, tunnel, flannel

As host-gw use IP routes to subnets via remote machine IPs, it looks like pure L3 network solution.

Therefore, why need direct L2 connectivity between hosts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`host-gw` adds route table entries on hosts, so that host know how to traffic container network packets.

This works on L2, because it only concerns `hosts`, `switches` and `containers`. `switches` does not care IP and route, `hosts` know `containers` exists, and how to route to them, `containers` just send and receive data.

If `hosts` are at different networks, L3 is introduced, and `routers` are involved. `routers` have no idea that `containers` exists, and any containers packet will be dropped, making communication impossible.

Of course, you can add route table entries on `routers`, but that is out of control `flannel`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this lab example to understand why `host-gw` is based on L2 connectivity. A 3 node cluster in the subnet `192.168.20.0/24` is running the `flannel` CNI plugin with `host-gw` as the backend. `flannel` assigns a piece of network to each node as follows:

node01 `192.168.20.200` gets `10.42.0.0/24`

node02 `192.168.20.201` gets `10.42.1.0/24`

node03 `192.168.20.202` gets `10.42.2.0/24`

Each `10...` range is the subnet that Pods will be assigned an IP from, when running on the respective node. Now each node knows about the ranges from the other two nodes (other irrelevant routes have been stripped):

```
user@node01 ~ $ ip r
10.42.1.0/24 via 192.168.20.201 dev enp0s3  <= node02
10.42.2.0/24 via 192.168.20.202 dev enp0s3  <= node03
```

```
user@node02 ~ $ ip r
10.42.0.0/24 via 192.168.20.200 dev enp0s3  <= node01
10.42.2.0/24 via 192.168.20.202 dev enp0s3  <= node03
```

```
user@node03 ~ $ ip r
10.42.0.0/24 via 192.168.20.200 dev enp0s3  <= node01
10.42.1.0/24 via 192.168.20.201 dev enp0s3  <= node02
```

When `node02` wants to send traffic to a Pod with IP `10.42.0.20`, by consulting its routing table it knows that the Pod's subnet is located on `node01`. The destination MAC of traffic destined for the Pod will be set to the MAC address of `node01`. `node01` then receives the packets and knows how to proceed further. All of that happens on L2, no L3 routing takes place. Also no encapsulation is involved.

Answer (score 0):

host-gw adds route table entires on each host. And the entries are as following:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.110.110.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
10.100.14.0     10.110.110.21   255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.100.38.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 docker0
10.110.110.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
169.254.169.254 10.110.110.1    255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 eth0
```

The most import item is the value of Gateway(10.110.110.21). The route table will change the destination mac address to the mac_address of node(10.110.110.21) which is connected L2 directly to 10.110.110.22(current node).

If not L2 connected, the packet can not be delivered to nodes(next-hop)